# Extract Certificate from Email

Tags: c#, email, ssl, outlook, certificate

as this is my first active time around here, if I ask stupidly - please forgive me.

I am having the following problem: I am trying to find out, if there is any way to extract the certificate from an email, wich then would be used for smime encryption. What I did find out is, that there seems not to be any way through the outlook object model, to get to the certificate, when sent via email. So i figured, that I could maybe just parse the source of the email. I would expect to find the Information somewhere in there.

Do you have any tips for me, on how to start on this problem? I did see, that there might be a way via openssl libraries for c# - would that be the right way to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide anything for that. But you can use the [RDOEncryptedMessage](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdoencryptedmessage.htm) object from the Redemption library.

Comment: Thansk for the reply!